# Calculating rotation of coordinate system

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, coordinate-systems, rotations

I have vector $w=(0,1)$ and unknow vector $v, w+v=u$, in two dimension coordinate system.
After performing rotation $R$ (angle is below 90*) vectors are $w', v', u'$.

If vector $v=0$ calculating $R$ when you know only $u'=w'$ is not a problem
$w'=Rw, R=w'w^{-1}$.

But what about the situation, when $v$ is not a zero vector. Is this possible to calculate $R$, when you only know $u'$ which is equal $w'+v'$ and $w$.

I have tons of papers with drawings, but i got nothing. Angle is below 90 degree, so $tg \theta$ is defined, but it seems to be not much helpfull.

Comment: Use the rotation matrix

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the normal 2D rotation matrix:
$$\mathbf{R} = \left [ \begin{matrix} \cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta) \\
\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta) \end{matrix} \right ] = \left [ \begin{matrix}
r_c & -r_s \\ r_s & r_c \end{matrix} \right ]$$
If $0° \le \theta \le 90°$, then $0 \le r_c \le 1$ and $0 \le r_s \le 1$.

Because $\mathbf{R}$ is a [real orthogonal matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix), we also have
$$\begin{cases}
r_c \in \mathbb{R} \\
r_s \in \mathbb{R} \\
r_c^2 + r_s^2 = 1
\end{cases}$$
In the first quadrant, $0° \le \theta \le 90°$, we can therefore say that
$$r_s = \sqrt{1 - r_c^2}$$
(Note that in general, $r_s = \pm \sqrt{1 - r_c^2}$, and $r_c = \pm \sqrt{1 - r_s^2}$.)

Now, let's say we have vectors
$$\begin{array}{l}
\vec{w} = ( 0 , 1 ) \\
\vec{p} = ( x_p , y_p ) \\
\vec{v} = ( x_v , y_v ) \end{array}$$
so that $\vec{w}+\vec{p}$ rotated by $\mathbf{R}$ yields $\vec{v}$:
$$\mathbf{R}\left(\vec{w} + \vec{p}\right) = \vec{v}$$
i.e.
$$\left [ \begin{matrix} r_c & -\sqrt{1-r_c^2} \\
\sqrt{1-r_c^2} & r_c \end{matrix} \right ] \left [ \begin{matrix} x_p \\ y_p + 1 \end{matrix} \right ] = \left [ \begin{matrix} x_v \\ y_v \end{matrix} \right ]$$
The above is essentially a pair of equations,
$$\begin{cases}
x_v = r_c x_p - \sqrt{1 - r_c^2} ( y_p + 1 ) \\
y_v = \sqrt{1 - r_c^2} x_p + r_c ( y_p + 1 ) \\
\end{cases}$$

If we knew $r_c$, then we could solve $( x_p , y_p )$ from the above:
$$\begin{cases}
x_p = x_v r_c + y_v \sqrt{1 - r_c^2} \\
y_p = y_v r_c - 1 - x_v \sqrt{1 - r_c^2} \end{cases} \tag{1}\label{1}$$

Oops. That means that you can choose any $r_c \in \mathbf{R}$, $0 \le r_c \le 1$, and there is at least one $\vec{p} = ( x_p , y_p )$ that fulfills the requirements!

In short, $r_c$ and therefore $\mathbf{R}$, cannot be determined if you only know $\vec{w}$ and $\vec{v}$ and nothing about $\vec{p}$.

(In OP's notation, knowing only $w$ and $w' + v'$ and nothing about $v$ is not sufficient to calculate the rotation matrix $R$.)

We need to know more about $\vec{p}$ to define $\mathbf{R}$. Its length (norm) is not sufficient, because we already know it; $\lVert \vec{w} + \vec{p} \rVert = \lVert \vec{v} \rVert$ because $\mathbf{R}$ is a pure rotation matrix, no scaling. You can apply restrictions on $\vec{p}$ using equation $\eqref{1}$ (in inequality form) and solving for $r_c$. The idea is, you need a sufficient restriction that limits $r_c$ to just one value (within $[0 , 1]$).